# Flutter Google Sign In error after selecting User Id: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, v1.b: 10: , null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm currently developing a Flutter Application for android and the web. However, the google sign-in feature is not working in the release mode or when you install an APK. It **does work** in Debug and Profile modes. I've tried numerous solutions, including changing the version dependencies of all firebase packages and the Google sign-in package. Updated Gradle, fixed the warning for "JAR files in the classpath should have the same version" and tried a few possible logic changes in the Authentication service code. Although the latter hardly seems to be the problem because the code is working in Debug mode and it was also previously working smoothly (in all modes).

I should mention the fact that I have added both SHA certificates (SHA 1 and SHA 256) from my laptop and also from the play store to make it ready for publishing but it didn't change anything. I also tried removing the Playstore SHA certificates but it doesn't help the problem either.

The error appears after the user clicks on the "Sign In with Google" Button and selects their google account. Below is the exact error I am facing (apart from Google Sign in other authentication services work).

```
E/flutter (13968): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, v1.b: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter (13968): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607)
E/flutter (13968): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167)
E/flutter (13968): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13968): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:367)
E/flutter (13968): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13968): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:266)
E/flutter (13968): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13968): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:399)
E/flutter (13968): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13968):
```

These are the version numbers of all my flutterfire packages and also google sign in:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^3.3.0 
  firebase_auth: ^3.5.1  
  firebase_core: ^1.20.1 
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.18  
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.2.1
```

NOTE: There is also a web version of the app, that is running fine in all run modes.

I would really appreciate any inputs on this problem! Thank you.

EDIT: Figured it out. Your release and debug SHA keys are different. First of all, add your debug SHA keys to firebase if it still doesn't work, add your release SHA key to firebase. Hope it will work!

Comment: facing the same issue, any update please ?

Comment: @RAITON try checking your API keys

Comment: Thanks for answer, problem resolved after adding google play key to firebase --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516426/platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception/73836061#73836061