# Platform Exception 10 on Google Sign In Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I'm trying to implement the google_sign_in oauth flow in my Flutter app without Firebase. So I've followed along multiple tutorials that took me through signing my app for debug, generating a key, etc.

However, on with the google_sign_in package, I still get this error:

> PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Googling it tells me to check my oauth consent flow and credentials. And I have checked it multiple times. I've inputted the right SHA1 key and the right app name.

I've migrated over to flutter_appauth instead, which launches a chrome custom tab and handles the oauth flow from there. And that actually works using the same client ID I was using in the Google Sign In flow.

However, I'd like to still get this resolved because it seems the google_sign_in has better compatibility with older android versions. So, does anybody have any idea what is causing this error?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516426/platformexceptionsign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception/73836061#73836061) could help you to achieve a solution. It has worked for others, because of the **ApiException: 10** problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Carlos. I've done what I could from that already and I'm still receiving the same errors sadly.

Comment: I have this problem as well and can't figure out how to solve it. Tried every suggestion that I've seen on the internet.

Comment: Yeah, use flutter_appauth instead. That worked for me somehow.